# Cleanest way to use combine multiple streams

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I am looking for a way to combine multiple streams, in this simple example I have 5 but I could easily have more.  I am currently using VS 2010, but might be moving to 2012.  So if any of F# 3.0 features help than I am open to those.

Would a computational builder help in this case?

```
let ``open`` = groupedByDay |> Observable.bind(fun group -> group |> Observable.map     (fun bar -> bar.Open) |> Observable.FirstAsync)
let high = groupedByDay |> Observable.bind(fun group -> group |> Observable.map (fun bar -> bar.High) |> Observable.Max)
let low = groupedByDay |> Observable.bind(fun group -> group |> Observable.map (fun bar -> bar.Low) |> Observable.Min)
let close = groupedByDay |> Observable.bind(fun group -> group |> Observable.map (fun     bar -> bar.Close,bar.Time) |> Observable.LastAsync)
let volume = groupedByDay |> Observable.bind(fun group -> group |> Observable.map (fun bar -> bar.Volume) |> Observable.Sum)
let combined = ``open``.And(high).And(low).And(close).And(volume).Then(fun o h l (c,t) v -> {Open = o; High = h; Low = l; Close = c; Time = t; Volume = v;})
            |> Observable.atwhen
            |> Observable.perform(log "Grouped") |> Observable.subscribe(fun _ -> ())
```

Comment: Does [`Observable.Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229590(v=vs.103).aspx) not do what you want?

Comment: No, I need to use Zip or And/Then/When.  The pairs have to be in sync.  In my example, the groups are by day.  I am running an operation to obtain a value for each day and than trying to merge back these results together.

Comment: Any reason _not_ to use `And`/`Then`?

Comment: Not particularly and it works well.  Just curious if there is a cleaner way, if not than that is fine too.

Comment: You could do something like `let merge a l =l |> List.fold (fun s v -> s.And v) a`

Comment: I'd drop the 'l' on both sides of that function, but otherwise it looks good.

Comment: @yamen Might as well also drop the 'a' then.